# Need to click on Contacts tab in Salesforce getting error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'defaultView')"

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, testng, salesforce-lightning

Through automated script wants to click on `Contacts tab in Salesforce`. But unable to do so.

**Getting error:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'defaultView')
  (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.81)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: '****-****', ip: '***.***.*.*', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '15.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 94.0.4606.81, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 93.0.4577.63 (ff5c0da2ec0ad..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Sristi\AppData\Loc...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:59263}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 0a464ae7e61949632bc4c84b5e790525
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
    at Automation.CreateTPARequest.loginTPAPortal(CreateTPARequest.java:60)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

I have tried below 3 scenarios, but none worked. This code was working till yesterday noon after evening getting above mentioned error :

1.

```
//driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebElement contacts=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='slds-context-bar']/one-app-nav-bar[@class='slds-grid slds-has-flexi-truncate']/nav[@class='slds-context-bar__secondary navCenter']/div/one-app-nav-bar-item-root[1]/a[@title='Contacts']/span[@class='slds-truncate' and text()='Contacts']"));
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        contacts.click();
```

2. 

```
//new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//nav[@class='slds-context-bar__secondary navCenter']/div/one-app-nav-bar-item-root[2]/a[@title='Contacts']"))).click();
```

3. 

```
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//nav[@class='slds-context-bar__secondary navCenter']/div/one-app-nav-bar-item-root[2]/a[@title='Contacts']")).click();
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant HTML code in text format please  ? Steps to copy `Press F12 in Chrome -> go to element section -> then right click on the element you want to share the outer HTML - > select copy and then outer HTML`

Comment: <a href="/lightning/o/Contact/home" title="Contacts" tabindex="0" draggable="false" aria-current="false" class="slds-context-bar__label-action dndItem"><span class="slds-truncate">Contacts</span></a>

Comment: Please see below.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 ways to click in Selenium.

I will use this xpath

```
//span[text()='Contacts']/parent::a[contains(@href,'lightning/o/Contact/home')]
```

**Code trial 1 :**

```
Thread.sleep(5);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Contacts']/parent::a[contains(@href,'lightning/o/Contact/home')]")).click();
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Contacts']/parent::a[contains(@href,'lightning/o/Contact/home')]"))).click();
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
Thread.sleep(5);
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Contacts']/parent::a[contains(@href,'lightning/o/Contact/home')]"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button);
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
Thread.sleep(5);
WebElement button  = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Contacts']/parent::a[contains(@href,'lightning/o/Contact/home')]"));
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(button).click().build().perform();
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.